# Chat Bot twitch IRC integration, Cannot get a response from NAMES 421 Unknown Command

Tags: javascript, chatbot, irc, twitch

I have successfully connected to twitch chat using the IRC starter [javascript program](https://github.com/TwitchDev/chat-samples/tree/master/javascript).

When running the program I am able to see messages to the channel I connect to, but whenever I send the `NAMES` signal via `socket.send('NAMES')`, twitch returns me a `421 unknown command` code.

What I would really like to know, is how can I get a list of users currently present in a channel?

My slightly modified version of the provided chat bot follows:

```
var chatClient = function chatClient(options){
    this.username = options.username;
    this.password = options.password;
    this.channel = options.channel;

    this.server = 'irc-ws.chat.twitch.tv';
    this.port = 443;
}

chatClient.prototype.open = function open(){
    this.webSocket = new WebSocket('wss://' + this.server + ':' + this.port + '/', 'irc');

    this.webSocket.onmessage = this.onMessage.bind(this);
    this.webSocket.onerror = this.onError.bind(this);
    this.webSocket.onclose = this.onClose.bind(this);
    this.webSocket.onopen = this.onOpen.bind(this);
};

chatClient.prototype.onError = function onError(message){
    console.log('Error: ' + message);
};

/* This is an example of a leaderboard scoring system. When someone sends a message to chat, we store 
   that value in local storage. It will show up when you click Populate Leaderboard in the UI. 
*/
chatClient.prototype.onMessage = function onMessage(message){
    if(message !== null){
        var parsed = this.parseMessage(message.data);
        if(parsed !== null){
            console.log(parsed)
            if(parsed.command === "PRIVMSG") {
                userPoints = localStorage.getItem(parsed.username);

                if(userPoints === null){
                    localStorage.setItem(parsed.username, 10);
                }
                else {
                    localStorage.setItem(parsed.username, parseFloat(userPoints) + 0.25);
                }
            } else if(parsed.command === "PING") {
                this.webSocket.send("PONG :" + parsed.message);
            }
        }
    }
};

chatClient.prototype.message = function message(){
    var socket = this.webSocket;

    console.log($(".message-text").val())

    if (socket !== null && socket.readyState === 1) {
        console.log("socket not null")
        socket.send("PRIVMSG " + this.channel + " :" + $(".message-text").val() + "\r\n")
        console.log("PRIVMSG " + this.channel + " :" + $(".message-text").val())
    }
}

chatClient.prototype.names = function names(){
    var socket = this.webSocket;

    if (socket !== null && socket.readyState === 1) {
        socket.send('NAMES')
    }
}    

chatClient.prototype.onOpen = function onOpen(){
    var socket = this.webSocket;

    if (socket !== null && socket.readyState === 1) {
        console.log('Initializing connection and authenticating...');
        console.log('username: ' + this.username);
        console.log('password: ' + this.password);
        console.log('channel: ' + this.channel);

        socket.send('PASS ' + this.password);
        socket.send('NICK ' + this.username);
        socket.send('JOIN ' + this.channel);
        socket.send('CAP REQ :twitch.tv/tags');
        socket.send('CAP REQ :twitch.tv/commands');
        socket.send('CAP REQ :twitch.tv/membership');
    }
};

chatClient.prototype.onClose = function onClose(){
    console.log('Disconnected from the chat server.');
};

chatClient.prototype.close = function close(){
    if(this.webSocket){
        this.webSocket.close();
    }
};

/* This is an example of an IRC message with tags. I split it across 
multiple lines for readability. The spaces at the beginning of each line are 
intentional to show where each set of information is parsed. */

//@badges=global_mod/1,turbo/1;color=#0D4200;display-name=TWITCH_UserNaME;emotes=25:0-4,12-16/1902:6-10;mod=0;room-id=1337;subscriber=0;turbo=1;user-id=1337;user-type=global_mod
// :twitch_username!twitch_username@twitch_username.tmi.twitch.tv 
// PRIVMSG 
// #channel
// :Kappa Keepo Kappa

chatClient.prototype.parseMessage = function parseMessage(rawMessage) {
    var parsedMessage = {
        message: null,
        tags: null,
        command: null,
        original: rawMessage,
        channel: null,
        username: null
    };

    if(rawMessage[0] === '@'){
        var tagIndex = rawMessage.indexOf(' '),
        userIndex = rawMessage.indexOf(' ', tagIndex + 1),
        commandIndex = rawMessage.indexOf(' ', userIndex + 1),
        channelIndex = rawMessage.indexOf(' ', commandIndex + 1),
        messageIndex = rawMessage.indexOf(':', channelIndex + 1);

        parsedMessage.tags = rawMessage.slice(0, tagIndex);
        parsedMessage.username = rawMessage.slice(tagIndex + 2, rawMessage.indexOf('!'));
        parsedMessage.command = rawMessage.slice(userIndex + 1, commandIndex);
        parsedMessage.channel = rawMessage.slice(commandIndex + 1, channelIndex);
        parsedMessage.message = rawMessage.slice(messageIndex + 1);
    } else if(rawMessage.startsWith("PING")) {
        parsedMessage.command = "PING";
        parsedMessage.message = rawMessage.split(":")[1];
    }

    return parsedMessage;
}

/* Builds out the top 10 leaderboard in the UI using a jQuery template. */
function buildLeaderboard(){
    var chatKeys = Object.keys(localStorage),
        outputTemplate = $('#entry-template').html(),
        leaderboard = $('.leaderboard-output'),
        sortedData = chatKeys.sort(function(a,b){
            return localStorage[b]-localStorage[a]
        });

    leaderboard.empty();

    for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        var viewerName = sortedData[i],
            template = $(outputTemplate);

        template.find('.rank').text(i + 1);
        template.find('.user-name').text(viewerName);
        template.find('.user-points').text(localStorage[viewerName]);

        leaderboard.append(template);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently Twitch IRCd doesn't support requesting NAMES command.
But it does support responding with NAMES upon joining the channel.

You did almost everything right.

In order to get the channel name list and to actually joining in, you should first submit your **CAP** requests and then join the channel. When the server will respond, he will also give you the channel name list.

**Actual order**

```
socket.send('CAP REQ :twitch.tv/tags');
socket.send('CAP REQ :twitch.tv/commands');
socket.send('CAP REQ :twitch.tv/membership');
socket.send('JOIN ' + this.channel);
```

Comment: Thanks so much for taking the time to respond, I'll upvote for now and then follow up this evening when I get home. Will mark as accepted if I'm able to get everything sorted out following this process.

Comment: Was able to get this working by adding some parsing for the awkward names message based on the number `353` in the response to join being sent last, as you described. Thanks a ton for your help, much obliged.